# REDUX: TypeSafe defintion of actions and reducers

Tags: typescript, redux, typesafe

In my quest to make my usage of Redux typesafe, I came up with the following construct:

```
export interface Action<T extends string, P> {
  readonly type: T;
  readonly payload: P;
};

export interface ActionBuilder<T extends string, P> {
  readonly type: T;
  readonly action: Action<T, P>;
  with(payload: P) : Action<T, P>;
};

const actionBuilder: <T extends string>(type: T) => <P>() => ActionBuilder<T, P> = 
  <T extends string>(type: T) => <P>() => <any>({with: (payload: P) => ({type, payload})});

const foo = actionBuilder("Foo")<{bar: string}>();
const bar = actionBuilder("Bar")<void>();

function test(action: typeof foo.action | typeof bar.action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "Foo": {
      const la = action.payload.bar; // compiler correctly infers that  "la" is a string
      break;
    }
    case bar.type: {
      const la = action.payload; // compiler correctly infers that "la" is a void
    }
  }
}

test(foo.with({bar: "yeah"}))
```

The only thing I don't like is to have this fake "action" field in ActionBuilder that I am just using in the "test"-signature to get a hook at the final action types. Any idea how to make this nicer?

Comment: Some coworkers of mine created a library to handle this exact type of thing. Feel free to check out https://github.com/palantir/redoodle/blob/master/src/TypedAction.ts and see if it's useful. I've been happy with how the library has worked out in projects I've written.

Comment: Just looked at your library. It used almost the same approach as mine above with the same "hack" in Defintion.TYPE...

Comment: Yup, you're right! I suppose that means that your approach might be the best available option right now, or at the least that it's a reasonable approach

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look at [redux-fluent](https://github.com/Code-Y/redux-fluent). It has been designed with a `typesafe developer experience` in mind!

[image]
[image]